# TypeScript - A function that returns a portion of the input

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I'm new to Typescript and I want to write a function that returns the object it receives but with less info.

Let's say I have a Type like that:

> type movie = {id: number, title:string, url:string, rating:number}

so I need a function that will receive an **array** of movies and return it only with id and title.

so if the input is:

> [{id:1, title:Wonder Woman, url: www, rating:5},{id:2, title: Super
>   Man, url:www2, rating:7}]

I need the output to be like that:

> [{id:1, title:Wonder Woman},{id:2, title: Super Man}]

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Well, yes. What have you tried? What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: `const doIt = (movies: movie[]) => movies.map(m => ({ id: m.id, title: m.title }));` 

Comment: I'll try that, I managed to create an array that looks like that -
[{1,wonder..},{2,super..}} it didn't print the fields names in the console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can signal to TS that you're working with *part* of a type (called a `Partial`) by using `Partial<...>`

```
type Movie = { id: string | number, name: string, url: string }

const movies: Movie[] = [
  { id: 1, name: "Movie A", url: "http://www.google.com" },
  { id: 2, name: "Movie B", url: "http://www.google.com" }
]

function stripUrl ({ id, name }: Movie): Partial<Movie> {
  return { id, name }
}

const mMovies = movies.map(stripUrl)
```

[image]